# How do we get the highest 2 values and the lowest 2 values of the same column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql table with products and price and I want to get 2 products with the highest price and 2 with the lowest price.

```
SELECT title, price
FROM products
GROUP BY price
ORDER BY price ASC limit 2
```

I tried this to get the lowest 2 values but how do I get the highest 2 in the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a union of two limit queries:

```
(SELECT title, price FROM products ORDER BY price LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT title, price FROM products ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 2)
```

The subqueries on the top and bottom will return the records corresponding to the 2 lowest and 2 highest prices, respectively.

Comment: while `union all` is usually what is wanted, in this case `union distinct` will prevent the same product being reported more than once when there are fewer than 4 products

Comment: @ysth I was aware of this edge case which is the deliberate reason why I suggested union with limit, rather than `ROW_NUMBER`.  In my mind, if there were only two data points, then the top two and bottom two are precisely the same, and should be reported twice.